# How to specify alternate Play! config?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm currently starting my application as follows:

> play run -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf

But Play seems to ignore this and uses the default application.conf. How can I specify a different config?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `play run -Dconfig.resource=prod`.

> `config.resource` specifies a resource name - not a basename, i.e. application and not application.conf

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Configuration

Comment: Hmm. Missed that in the docs.. but that still doesn't work.

The only way I could get it working is if I do:
play -Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf run
Additionally, the config parameter must be specified *before* the run statement. ie: play run -Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf, will not work. Note: the *DConfig.resource* parameter *does not work at all*.

Comment: Weird - the typesafe config library that Play configuration is based on document says it's exactly the other way around: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

Answer (score 0):

The syntax I know goes like:

```
play -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf run
```